# Long time to launch apps, but only on single desktop

Tags: nvidia, gnome, multiple-monitors, snap, 23.10

I have what normally looks a fairly common problem: when I boot in Ubuntu 23.10 and I click on an app on the dock, it takes a really long time (30s to 1m) to launch -- and sometimes it doesn't launch at all.

Differently from the problems I saw around, this problem does *not* happen if my laptop is plugged to its docking station with two external monitors, or via an HDMI cable to a projector. (I'm always plugged into the power when I test)

Interestingly, I want to be in night mode, but some apps (for instance `nautilus`) are still bright, while others are dark (for instance `firefox`) -- this happens when I'm plugged in the working station. Occasionally, `nautilus` would be in night mode, when the laptop is not plugged into a docking station.

My setup is a Dell Precision 7760, with a NVIDIA RTX A4000 Laptop GPU with properly installed nvidia-driver-535 (I'm using it to do GPU computations with CUDA version 12.2, so I know it works as it should). I'm using the standard GNOME desktop environment, but when I go to settings to check the version, it says "GNOME Version Not Available". `gnome-shell --version` says 45.0. I don't know what logs could help answer the question, but I will update the question if somebody asks.

Reading around, I tried fiddling with installing/removing `appmenu-gtk2-module` and `xdg-desktop-portal-gtk`, to no avail. I have recently updated from 22.04 and, on the very same machine, this problem was not present.

**UPDATE #1**:

The apps that are currently affected by this issue are `firefox`, `nautilus`, the terminal, and `gnome-text-editor`.

When launching `firefox` from terminal, it says `Gtk-Message: 11:43:52.258: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"`. `appmenu-gtk-module` doesn't exist and I have `appmenu-gtk2-module` installed. So I tried to install `appmenu-gtk3-module` instead. Now the warning message is different:

```
Unable to query dbus: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.109" (uid=1000 pid=3375 comm="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox" label="firefox (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="ListNames" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)
```

A couple of other things I noticed when testing more in depth:

This seems to be related to `snap` apps, because I installed `filezilla` and `gimp` via apt-get and they launch just fine (`gimp` complains about a missing `canberra-gtk-module` but it doesn't really affect launch time). This is confirmed by installing `gedit` via apt-get and having it launch just fine, when instead `gnome-text-editor` suffers. However, removing snap `firefox` and installing it via apt didn't solve the issue for `firefox`.

Another thing is that `nautilus` launches fine if I wait a long time before attempting to launch it. If I do, it will start in dark mode. If instead I try to launch it a few seconds after boot, it will take a long time to launch and it will start in bright mode. Launching it from terminal doesn't produce any relevant or interesting messages.

Comment: start by running the command for one of these apps from the terminal and see if there is something interesting. For instance a notice that gets repeated a lot that keeps this app from working where the system either gives up or it then does work.

Comment: Thank you. Your comments made me try a few more things that are too long to report here. See the update #1 edit in the post.

Comment: if snap... all snaps can be replaced by their apt versions, Snaps can use connections to the web to check their status. That could be taking longer than expected.

Comment: Unfortunately, replacing firefox from snap to apt didn't solve its issue. Also it wouldn't really explain why everything works fine provided that I'm either on a docking station with external monitors, or with a plugged-in HDMI cable.

Comment: I suggest you run `sudo apt reinstall gnome-shell snapd apparmor` and then reboot your system to see if things get better ... That will reinstall the three packages that seem to be related to what you describe if, for example, they were not completely upgraded/configured during the last system upgrade.

Comment: I don't know if related, but I had to remove all desktop-portal apps to regain my fast startups. But this will only be valid for a "snap-free" system, which I currently have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem after 23.04 → 23.10 update. The above question was the closest to my problem. I noticed the following errors while launching my applications:

```
Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop': timed out (service_start_timeout=120000ms)
Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gnome': timed out (service_start_timeout=120000ms)
```

On another forum I found the solution related to these messages to be:

```
$ sudo apt purge xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
```

After that, I no longer have these timeouts that slow down the launching of those applications.

Also note @kanehekili's comment above. (Please, ignore they last sentence about the "snap-free" system, because I think it is not relevant.)

Comment: This saved my on Ubuntu 23.10, but I can help wonder what are the implications of  purging xdg-desktop-portal-gnome? From what I have read,  xdg-desktop-portal-gnome is responsible for allowing sandboxed applications to request services from outside the sandbox. Does this imply that by removing it, certain apps may not be able to access services?

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same issue on a new build of Ubuntu 23.10.

Removing `xdg-desktop-portal-gnome` did resolve the issue, but I wasn't sure what I would be missing by keeping it removed so I added it back, and the problem re-occured.

However I noticed my session was running X11.

Relogging in under Wayland also appears to have cured the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that the wrong driver was selected.
So I just fixed it by changing to another driver and issue fixed.
Go to Additional driver and change to another available driver and restart the computer.
In my case I was using x.org server's graphic driver where skype was not working.
So I changed to the Nvidia driver and it worked.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]